# combine two jquery functions in one

Tags: jquery, function

I am trying to combine two functions together to fire up at the same time.

I have this code that autoloads next page based on a timer (2-5sec after) when youtube video ends, it is based on youtube api.

```
        // when video ends
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if(event.data === 0) { 
            setTimeout(function(){
            var link = jQuery('.prev-post a').attr('href');
            var className = jQuery('#tm-autonext span#autonext').attr('class');
            //alert(className);
            if(className!=''){
              if(link !=undefined){
                  window.location.href= link;
              }
            }
            },<?php echo $delay_video ?>);
        }
    }
```

I would like to add a function to remove a "hidden" class from some div also after the video end. so the end result would be that when a video ends, a dialog div is removed of its "hidden" class, and will show up for the amount of time before the autoload to the next page.

so i have this div:
        
        
        ...
        ...
        ...

and a function to remove the hidden class, and show a little timer:

```
 function hideVideo() {
 $('#dialog-modal').removeClass('hidden');
 var i = 0;
            var countdown = document.getElementById("countdown");
            setInterval(function() {
            countdown.innerText = 5-i;
                if (i++ == 5) {
                            }
            }, 1000);
 }
```

I would like to combine them together, will appreciate any help, as i was breaking my head around it, and cant make it work.

Comment: You're changing the location, in other words you're redirecting to another page, and all javascript and HTML is lost, so changing a class on the page you're leaving won't really matter.

Comment: yeah but there is a timer that prevents the page to redirect for about 5 seconds, so i want to show this div (dialog) for exactly that time, after the redirection begins i want the div to be hidden again